# Visualize a .ply file with a pointcloud in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, pointcloud, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

i'm looking for a method that could help me visualize a pointcloud in .ply format, saved from LSD (pressing the "p" while it is mapping) in Rviz.
did somebody could help me?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203244/visualize-a-.ply-file-with-a-pointcloud-in-rviz/) by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read the [last section ("Troubleshoot / FAQ") of the LSD documentation](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam#6-troubleshoot--faq). Quote:

> How can I get the live-pointcloud in ROS to use with RVIZ?
>
> You cannot, at least not on-line and in real-time. The reason is [...]

They provide a viewer node that you should probably use instead of RViz for this purpose.

If you want to visualize a ply file offline, don't use RViz, use MeshLab or some other ply viewer instead.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-02-17**:
thanks, yes i know about the FAQ, i so decide to visualize not in real time the pointcloud using the "p" button and visualize before the mapping.
all this cause i need to visualize the ponintcloud in Rviz... yet control the pointcloud with meshlab and it is all right, now i need to see it in Rviz...

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-17**:
So you want to take a previously recorded map (as .ply) and show it in RViz? As it said in the FAQ, this will only work for very small maps. You should write a small node that reads PLY and publishes PointCloud2. This will be useful: http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_p_l_y_reader.html

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-02-17**:
i'm having some problems:
for using functions that convert/visualize from a .ply file, i need the ply:io.h for the #include, but i don't have it in my pcl directory.
i'm using ros hydro.
somebody could helpe me?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-17**:
This is the include you need:

```
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
```

You can get it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libpcl-io-1.7-dev
```

It should be installed here:

```
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/ply_io.h
```

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-02-17**:
i don't have pcl-1.7
this is probably the cause of the missing libraries...
but i cannot find it for hydro, all i can find on github for hydro is:
https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl
and libraries aren't in there

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-02-17**:
If you have ros-hydro-perception-pcl installed, you should also have the libpcl-* packages installed, since they are dependencies of ros-hydro-perception-pcl. What do you mean you cannot find it for hydro? Did you try the apt-get command from my last comment? Is the file there?

**Comment by [JacoPisa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20532/jacopisa/) on 2015-02-18**:
using catkin, i have only the same directories etc that you could see here https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl. i'm doing it in the wrong way?? after i use catkin_make and it run, but without the lib ply and i cannot use your apt-get